# I have a issue with my update query and i cannot tell what it is

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, ms-access, oledbcommand

I checked this query over and over again and I cant tell what the problem is.

```
using (OleDbConnection connection = getConnection())
{
    string update = 
       "UPDATE Course SET SchoolID = @SchoolID, SchoolID2 = @SchoolID2, StatusID = @StatusID," +
       "Bannercode = @Bannercode, CourseName = @CourseName, Description = @Description, Credits = @Credits," +
       "Prereqs = @Prereqs, URL = @URL, Keywords = @Keywords, Email = @Email, Approved = @Approved, ApprovedBY = @ApprovedBY," +
       "ApprovedWhen = @ApprovedWhen, History = @History, Level = @Level WHERE ID = @ID";
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(update,connection); 
    OleDbParameter pram1 = new OleDbParameter("@SchoolID", SchoolID);
    command.Parameters.Add(pram1); 
    OleDbParameter pram2 = new OleDbParameter("@SchoolID2", SchoolID2); 
    command.Parameters.Add(pram2);
    OleDbParameter pram3 = new OleDbParameter("@StatusID", StatusID);
    command.Parameters.Add(pram3); 
    OleDbParameter pram4 = new OleDbParameter("@Bannercode", Bannercode);
    command.Parameters.Add(pram4); 
    OleDbParameter pram5 = new OleDbParameter("@CourseName", CourseName); 
    command.Parameters.Add(pram5);
    OleDbParameter pram6 = new OleDbParameter("@Description", Description);
    command.Parameters.Add(pram6); 
    OleDbParameter pram7 = new OleDbParameter("@Credits", Credits);
    command.Parameters.Add(pram7); 
    OleDbParameter pram8= new OleDbParameter("@Prereqs", Prereqs); 
    command.Parameters.Add(pram8); 
    OleDbParameter pram9 = new OleDbParameter("@URL", URL); 
    command.Parameters.Add(pram9);
    OleDbParameter pram10 = new OleDbParameter("@Keywords", Keywords); 
    command.Parameters.Add(pram10); 
    OleDbParameter pram11 = new OleDbParameter("@Email", Email); 
    command.Parameters.Add(pram11); 
    OleDbParameter pram12 = new OleDbParameter("@Approved", Approved); 
    command.Parameters.Add(pram12); 
    OleDbParameter pram14 = new OleDbParameter("@ApprovedBY", ApprovedBY); 
    command.Parameters.Add(pram14);
```

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: Syntax error in UPDATE statement.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Syntax error in UPDATE statement.

Comment: OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(update,connection);
                    OleDbParameter pram1 = new OleDbParameter("@SchoolID", SchoolID);
                    command.Parameters.Add(pram1);
                    OleDbParameter pram2 = new OleDbParameter("@SchoolID2", SchoolID2);
                    command.Parameters.Add(pram2);

Comment: OleDbParameter pram3 = new OleDbParameter("@StatusID", StatusID);
                    command.Parameters.Add(pram3);
                    OleDbParameter pram4 = new OleDbParameter("@Bannercode", Bannercode);
                    command.Parameters.Add(pram4);
                    OleDbParameter pram5 = new OleDbParameter("@CourseName", CourseName);
                    command.Parameters.Add(pram5);

Comment: OleDbParameter pram6 = new OleDbParameter("@Description", Description);
                    command.Parameters.Add(pram6);
                    OleDbParameter pram7 = new OleDbParameter("@Credits", Credits);
                    command.Parameters.Add(pram7);
                    OleDbParameter pram8= new OleDbParameter("@Prereqs", Prereqs);
                    command.Parameters.Add(pram8);
                    OleDbParameter pram9 = new OleDbParameter("@URL", URL);
                    command.Parameters.Add(pram9);

Comment: OleDbParameter pram10 = new OleDbParameter("@Keywords", Keywords);
                    command.Parameters.Add(pram10);
                    OleDbParameter pram11 = new OleDbParameter("@Email", Email);
                    command.Parameters.Add(pram11);
                    OleDbParameter pram12 = new OleDbParameter("@Approved", Approved);
                    command.Parameters.Add(pram12);
                    OleDbParameter pram14 = new OleDbParameter("@ApprovedBY", ApprovedBY);
                    command.Parameters.Add(pram14);

Comment: Did you see the link button 'edit' under your original question?

Comment: it keeps notifying me to add more description as it was mostly made up of code

Comment: You can simplify your code. E.g: `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SchoolID", SchoolID);`

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that you are using MS-Access as database behind the OleDb. If this is the case then the LEVEL word is a reserved keyword and you need to put it between square brackets

```
... [Level] = @Level WHERE ID = @ID";
```

Your code could be better written if you use a different method to prepare the parameter collection. 
For example

```
command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Prereqs", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Prereqs;
```

Specifying the OleDbType of the parameters helps the engine to disambiguate between the Value and the Type when the Value is zero.
[Look at this article on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9dd8zze1(v=vs.110).aspx) that explain why you should avoid using this form of the Add method of the OleDbParameterCollection (The article is for SqlParameterCollection but the same is true for OleDb)

Comment: I included the brackets and its given me this error, "No value given for one or more required parameters."

Comment: Looks like @steve's answer fixed your initial error. Now check if any of the values you're passing in for required parameters are null.

Comment: Sorry about that. I managed to fix the issue. However now it says "Parameter @Prereqs has no default value."  Appreciate your help thanks!

Comment: Check accurately if your field is exactly named `Prereqs`

Comment: Iv'e applied the brackets to all columns and the table name. Could this be the reason why I get this error. "Parameter @Prereqs has no default value."

Comment: By the way, the code that I have added to your question contains only 14 parameters, your query requires 18 parameters. Did you have added the other 4 parameters to your command?

Comment: Yep Iv'e checked, in fact I copied and pasted it to make sure.

Comment: I wasn't able to add the rest of the code because the form requires that i add more description as the question is made up of mostly code.

Comment: Yep the other four parameters have been added.

Comment: What is the datatype of the variable Prereqs added to the parameter. Is it an Integer? If yes what is its value? If this value is zero then there is a known problem with the method Add

Comment: These are the.. public static void UpdateCourses(int ID, int SchoolID, int SchoolID2, string StatusID, string Bannercode,
                string CourseName, string Description, int Credits, string Prereqs, string URL, string Keywords,
                string Email, string Approved, string ApprovedBY, string ApprovedWhen, string History, string Level)
            {

Comment: I haven't given it a value. If this helps at all, In my access data base the column Prereqs data type is long text.

Comment: I gave the code you provided above a try and it still gave me the same error. So I removed Prereqs all together and got the same error but for URL. Thanks ever so much for your help i really appreciate it. I will try and construct this in a different way and see how it goes. This is just simply frustrating.